# TFS2015: No gated check-in build triggered for changes

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a series of vNext gated check-in build definitions; each one is "watching" different source control folders.

They all work fine till one of them starts to miss the changesets; from that moment I can check-in from Visual Studio without getting the notification window and without triggering the build.

In order to restore the functionality I have to make a dummy modification to the build definition(like adding a letter to the description) and save it. Then it starts working.

Do you know in which logs/databases I have to check to see why the builds are not triggered?

Answer (score 2):

I have met same situation. And checked everywhere including event logs or database. **Nothing!**

Seems the build definition hangs on with some unknown reason. Edit it will update the definition on the server. And everything works well again.

As a workaround, my team finally deleted the definition and crated a new one with the same configuration.

Comment: My workaround it'll be to create a PowerShell script that'll run every day and it'll update all build vNext definitions.

Comment: Did you ever run in to the issue again with the new definition?